# How works a form outside the associated model's view?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-submit

I have a problem that seems very simple to me, but I can't figure out the solution. So if you can be of any help, I would appreciate that very much :-)

First of all, I used the Devise gem to create my Users.

Here is **app/models/user.rb** :

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :default_values
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar, :address, :longitude, :latitude

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "50x50>" },
                         url: "users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                         path: ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                         default_url: "users/missing/:style/missing.png"


  #Geokit
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  def default_values
    self.address ||= "Paris"
    self.geocode
  end

end
```

I created a Home controller for my static pages, and my root_path is **app/views/home/index.html.erb** in which we can find :

```rb
<%= render 'new_name' %>
```

Let's take a look at this **app/views/home/_new_name.html.erb** :

```rb
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#yourName" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">OK</a>

 <!-- Modal -->
<div id="yourName" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel"><%= t('home.your_name') %></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(@current_user) do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :name, t('name'), placeholder: t('home.your_name') %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit t('update'), class: "btn"%>
      </p>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And yes, I definitely used the bootsrap's magic ;-)

For the record, my **config/routes.rb**

```rb
Dindon::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "home#index"

  resources :products

  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user
  match 'users' => 'users#index'
end
```

So, the last thing to do is configure my HomeController to give to my instance variable @current_user his new name. Here is my **app/controllers/home_controller.rb** :

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @current_user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    @current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work at all. When I click on the OK button, I have the window, I fill in the field, I click on the submit button, and it send me to the User show view, but without taking the change of name in account.

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

doesn't look like you define @current_user in your update method.

Also you use form_for(@user) whereas you are trying to get params[:user] in your update method, which is inconsistent.

In my opinion,you should either define @current_user before updating it ( using params, as you do it in index), or directly use the devise *current_user* method ( note that there is no @ here, so we are calling a devise method, not an instance variable ).

Note that calling *current_user* will update the logged user that clicked, whereas using the find method will allow you to modify any other user, as long as a valid id is provided in the parameters.